# What benefit does the ImmutableObject attribute provide?

Tags: .net, vb.net, immutability, mutable

I was testing the `ImmutableObjectAttribute` attribute just for curiosity to see if I could gain some beneffits applying it, or if it was just for semantic decoration...

- **[ImmutableObjectAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.immutableobjectattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

> Specifies that an object has no subproperties capable of being edited.

So I have this class:

```
<ImmutableObject(True)>
Public Class TestClass

    <ImmutableObject(True)>
    Public sb As StringBuilder

    Public Sub New()
        sb = New StringBuilder
    End Sub

End Class
```

And I've tested with this code:

```
    Dim obj As New TestClass

    obj.sb.Append("Hello")
    obj.sb.Append(" ")
    obj.sb.Append("World")

    MsgBox(obj.sb.ToString)
```

Then, after I'd applied the `ImmutableObject` attribute in a mutable object, I expected to see some kind of compiler warning, some sort of runtime exception, or just receive an unexpected value from the internal string of the `StringBuilder`, but nothing of that things happened, all seems to work as normally.

That makes me think a question whose answer seems obvious, but I need to ask it:

- Is the `ImmutableObject` attribute just a decorative attribute?.

Why exists this attribute then? I cannot find any beneffit marking a class with this attribute it it not ensures that the members are really immutable, or at least what .Net understands for immutable (you know, like a String is not really immutable in .Net).

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/zplbt7m

Comment: Attributes generally dont do anything by themselves to a Type.  Just as `DefaultValue` doesnt provide or enforce a default, and `Range` doesnt enforce a range,  They are meta-data and generally for something else to read and act on.  And strings are immutable.  `myString(x) = "x"c` wont work.

Comment: A string is immutable if seen from our side, but is not immutable at all since it has an internal method which StringBuilder uses to alter the state of the string (not to assign a new string). thanks for comment!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [ImmutableObjectAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.immutableobjectattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> This attribute is typically used in the Properties window to determine
>   whether to render an expandable object as read-only. As such, *this
>   property is used only at design time.*

... so yes, this is only for decoration.

Comment: The damn remarks sections from MSDN... I hate to forgot to read them, hehe. Thankyou!